# Htaccess skip blank line problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a bit of a problem with `.htaccess` and numbers.

I have a directory

```
       http://somedomain.com/directory/
```

When I add a  number to it, I want to use htaccess to create a variable.

```
       http://somedomain.com/directory/

       RewriteRule ^[0-9]+$ index.php?action=viewclient&clientnumber=$1 [L]
```

When I put this URL, I want the clientnumber to be created

```
       http://somedomain.com/directory/5
```

However, when I put no number in it, it still creates the `$action` variable with a blank `$clientnumber`.

```
       http://somedomain.com/directory/
```

Is there a change I need to make to the htaccess to **only** add these variables if there is a number in the URL but blank. To skip this htaccess line if no variable is added.

Thankyou

EDIT: i cant get the URL's to work. from the answers provided. i'm off to bed & will re-check this over the weekend.

if I put /directory/ I get what i want. if i put /directory/4  or directory/87 (any number) i get a 404 error.

EDIT2 - WEIRD ???

I'm off to bed, but decided to try again & selected a different client. the URLs are the SAME format.

some clients work (display the correct page), other URL's (CORRECT URL), show a 404 page.

I'll try & debug more in the weekend. - very weird. (I'll add a debug script / log at the top of my index.php - to see if the page is even loading.)

EDIT 3:- I've added a small log script at the top of index.php - it DOES record the valid / working URLs, but does not activate if its a 404 error (the error is the SAME format URL - so should activate index.php - & then my index.php should do the calcualtions / checks to see if the values are valid. but its not even getting to my php script.

OK, i'm off to bed - will retry in the weekend.

Comment: You can set action to do in your index.php like
`if(!isset($_GET['clientnumber'])){ DO_REDIRECT_HERE }`

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file relative to directory? Do you have AllowOverride All set for that location? Have you made sure `RewriteEngine On` is set (IE that RewriteRules are being executed).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+$ index.php?action=viewclient&clientnumber=$1 [L]
```

`$1` refers to the first *capture group*. You don't have any capture groups in your regular expression. This is correct:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=viewclient&clientnumber=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing it to

`RewriteRule ^([0-9])$ index.php?action=viewclient&clientnumber=$1 [L]`

(no + after [0-9] )

will mean the rule is only executed if the number 0-9 is present in the request

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, was focusing on this: "Is there a change I need to make to the htaccess to only add these variables if there is a number in the URL"